# Do I have to call kernel.Get to instantiate an object when using Ninject?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, ninject

So many of the examples for Ninject are very, very basic.  It's either just a controller, or they create the kernel and the object's in a single function for demonstration purposes.

So for some reason I thought that you could just instantiate an object like normal, and Ninject would intercept that and work.  For instance:

```
public class foo 
{
    public foo(IInjectable injected)
    {
       //stuff
    }
}
```

Then somewhere in another class you could do:

```
var fooObject = new foo();
```

So am I supposed to use kernel.get instead?

Then, if I DO need to keep calling the kernel how do I pass that around to everything that needs it?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this help http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/4/dependency_injection_using_ninject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you design your application well then there should only be only a single `Kernel.Get` request happening in your application (often via something like like `Ninject.MVC3`). Usually that is where the root object of your application gets instantiated (for example MainViewModel of your application shell). All other types simply declare their dependencies in the constructor without knowing who is responsible for creating and managing their dependencies. Little example

```
public class Main {
   // Somewhere
   var mainViewModel = Kernel.Get<MainViewModel>();
   mainViewModel.Initialize();
}

public class MainViewModel {
    ctor(ISectionViewModelFactory factory, ISectionViewModel sectionViewModel) {
    }

    public void Initialize() {
       // use injected factory etc.
    }
}

public class ApplicationModule : NinjectModule {

   public override void Load() {
      Bind<ISectionViewModel>().To<SectionViewModel>();
      Bind<ISectionViewModelFactory>().ToFactory(); // <-- requires factory extension
   }
}
```

and the application builds itself up without accessing the kernel elsewhere.

See [the factory extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki) for the `ToFactory()` bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach here would only work if you also inject *foo* (in general it's not a good idea to start injecting the kernel into your classes, as it starts to un-invert the inversion of control, so to speak).

It's hard to tell without some context, but let's say your code above is contained in another class *bar*.  Then you'd proceed like so:

```
public class bar
{
    foo _fooObject;

    public bar(foo fooObject)
    {
        _fooObject = fooObject;
    }
}
```

And then of course the binding for *foo* would be set up, for example:

```
Bind<foo>.ToSelf();
```

If you need to create multiple instances of *foo* within *bar*, then you could use a factory:

```
public class bar
{
    fooFactory _factory;

    public bar(fooFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    void baz()
    {
        foo fooObject = _factory.GetNew();
    }
}
```

Comment: Although given he's using Ninject, he's prob actually use https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki (though no harm for pedagogical reasons to do it long hand as you do)